# Get the substring between two given words in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, as shown below. What i want is to get the substring between the two given words in columns **[word1]** and **[word2]** and save the result a new column **[result]**:

```
index   string                                      word1   word2   result

1       This is a very simple string!               is      string  a very simple
2       Again! This is a very simple string         Again   very    !This is a
```

I know how to do it in a simple string, like below, but what i want is how to apply it in a dataframe.

```
s = "123ddddddabc"

def find_between(s, first, last):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""
print (find_between( s, "123", "abc" ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply + Lambda shall do the trick.

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: find_between(row['string'], row['word1'], row['word2']), axis=1)
```